# why does python change the original parameter

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send a http request,but have a problem with the params,The following is my code:

```
my_url="mysite.com/api"
payload = {'start':"2017-04-01%2000:00:00",'end':"017-04-01%2023:59:59"}
r=requests.get(my_url,params=payload)
print r.request.url
```

The url sent is `"mysite.com/api?start=2017-04-01%252000%3A00%3A00&end=2017-04-01%252023%3A59%3A59'`, the params is changed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You're trying to combine direct urls with a library's interpretation of a url. What is the exact get request you're trying to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is URL encoding the information for you.  Certain characters aren't allowed during HTTP transmission (because they serve specific functions in the protocol).  If you want to use illegal characters like `:` and (space) then you can URL encode them to `%3A` and `%20`.  URL encoding is standardized, so you can send your information (post encoding) then a server will receive it and decode it, resulting in them receiving your original message.

Here's a more in depth analysis of it:
https://www.thoughtco.com/encoding-urls-3467463

Comment: I modify the params like payload = {'start':"2017-04-01%252000%3A00%3A00",'end':"017-04-01%252023%3A59%3A59"}, still cannot work

Comment: Requests will auto encode the special characters, and I resolved this by unquote it manually then resend the request